# Align in a fraction, arbitrary part of denominator with part of the numerator

Tags: align, fractions

I am trying to align the bottom part of a "fraction" with the top part, but since I am new to this, I am not sure the right way.

The goal is for the `q` in the "denominator" to line up with the `p`'s above, and the `∴` would end up to the left, and not under the line. Is this possible?

```
\displaystyle
\frac{
\begin{align*}
&p
\\
&p→q
\end{align*}
}
{\begin{align*}
∴ &q
\end{align*}}
```

[image]

Comment: please show a small but complete document, not a fragment we can not test. `align*` is a top level display that must be started outside math mode and produces the entire display you can not use it inside math. You are possibly looking for `aligned` or `array`

Comment: Take a look at the ebproof package.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am only using this in WordPress with the MathJax plugin, it doesn't let me use the full document syntax. I have never used LaTeX before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the desired output this is one way

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{rl}
&p\\
&p \to q \\
\cline{2-2}
\therefore & q
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

but I believe there are dedicated packages for logical proofs.

Comment: This is the result I am looking for. It's not working in WordPress MathJax, but thanks for showing how it could be done.

Comment: @Paul Sorry, but MathJax is off-topic on this site. While its syntax is based on TeX's, it is en entirely different thing.

Comment: I understand, thank you

Comment: @Paul MathJax does not support `\cline`. It might work with `\begin{array}{l} p \\ p \to q \\ \hline \llap{\therefore\quad} q \end{array}` but as I said this is unfortunately off-topic.

Comment: That does work nicely, thanks again!

Comment: That exact package is ebproof :-)